# How to run matlab .m files in google colab

Tags: python-2.7, matlab, pytorch, google-colaboratory, torchvision

I am currently trying to run this repo
https://github.com/Fanziapril/mvfnet
which requires a step:

```
"Run the Matlab/ModelGeneration/ModelGenerate.m to generate the shape
model "Model_Shape.mat" and copy it to the Matlab/"
```

Is it possible to run a `.m` file in **colab** to do this?

Also, I have looked into oct2py library 
https://blink1073.github.io/oct2py/,
but was not able to successfully run the file.
I followed this [How to run a MATLAB code on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51406331/how-to-run-a-matlab-code-on-python)

Comment: I think Google Colab can only run iPython notebooks and some bash commands through the iPython notebook, so you could try to run the .m file by uploading it to Colab and using `!matlab file.m` (basically replace matlab with maybe octave or some other MATLAB compiler which can be installed in Colab, and you use exclamation mark before the command to indicate it is to be run like a bash command).

Answer (score 8):

You need to first install octave with

```
!apt install octave
```

Then you can run your m-file with

```
!octave -W file.m
```

Here's a [minimal example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1x7Sgb-Io9iYCE-YEtx8zi7K8mXzBWAeC).

Comment: after getting the mat file generated, I get raise ValueError('Unknown mat file type, version %s, %s' % ret)
ValueError: Unknown mat file type, version 57, 54