# Call MATLAB from Google Colab

Tags: matlab, google-colaboratory

Is it possible to used MATLAB commands from Google Colab (Jupiter on cloud)?

For example, I would like to call Risk Management Toolbox functions like bin(vbt, Name, Value), tbfi(vbt, Name, Value) or tuff(vbt, Name, Value) in Google Colab.

I tried without success

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Google Colab runs its Python code on Google's server-side Python environment. I don't think Google has bought Matlab for everybody.

Some Matlab code can be run under [GNU Octave](https://octave.org/), a FLOSS clone of Matlab. That can be installed in your Google Colab session's environment by calling `!apt install octave` in a notebook cell.

Comment: This answer isn't up to date

Comment: @SharonasYkm Interesting. Can you provide any links to doco on what has changed? I can't find anything by googling. Ordinarily I'd just delete this answer, because I don't care to spend time on a conversation like this on a minor answer, but it has been Accepted, so Stack Overflow won't let me delete it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56416657/how-to-run-matlab-m-files-in-google-colab

Comment: That answer doesn't look like it makes this one wrong. That is using GNU Octave, not Matlab. Octave is a FLOSS clone of Matlab. And that looks like it is doing the installation on the server side. Might be worth mentioning, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
To activate this option use:

```
!apt install octave
```

Comment: octave == MATLAB ->  False