# Python : .p file with MATLAB function

Tags: python, matlab

I have a .p file (for the example named EX1.p) that contains a MATLAB function that I need in my python code and I tried to import the file/the function but with no success.
Hope someone can help

Comment: Why do you assume that importing file with function written in *different* programming lanaguage should just work?

Comment: Because is it part of an exercise in one of my courses (-_-')

Comment: Maybe ask your instructor for more guidance. P-files are encrypted and can only be run by MATLAB, they cannot be edited. Maybe you are supposed to call MATLAB from within Python? Or maybe you are not supposed to use Python at all?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is at least two options: oct2py (only valid if your code may be run in Octave) and Matlab Engine. You can find an explanation of both options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51406331/how-to-run-matlab-code-from-within-python).

Comment: P-files don't run in Octave though. They're an encoded version of an M-file, intended to hide the code from the users.

Comment: That's true, it's encrypted code. Therefore, the only option is the Matlab engine, explained by Mathworks here (https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html)